# Redirect then execute

Tags: php, powershell, redirect, shell-exec

I'm trying to go to the loading page and then execute the powershell script. But unfortunately I can't get this to work. When I go to the page it automaticaly goes to the script and redirects me to the succes of fail page.
I have tried to do a sleep after the redirect but it just waits few seconds and then runs the script and redirects me to the html page.

```
        header('Location: /loading.html');
        include ("file\where\the\variable\comes\from.php");
        $s = shell_exec("powershell path\\to\\script.ps1 '$variable'< NUL");

        if (strpos($s, 'True') === false) {
        header('Location: /succes.html'); 
        }
        else{
        header('Location: /failed.html'); 
        }
```

Comment: You're missing `exit();`. Your script is dying at your first `header()` because it feels the need to redirect but cannot continue because of an unknown end. You `include()` or `require_once()` your loading page and then add an `exit();` after each `header()` method. [See how it should be here](https://3v4l.org/sh7J3)

Comment: Why do you use a redirect first and only after the redirect you are callin the shell script?
As far as I know, what happens here is: 
1. Server sends redirect header to browser. (first line in your code)
2. Browser asks for loading.html
3. Server sends loading.html to browser 
The rest of the script will remain unexecuted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A loading page is not possible in this construction because your page only displays when your file is finished with loading. If you would run the include / shell through an AJAX request it would. The solution below is the index page (loading.html) that runs an AJAX request to the file request.php and copies his contents into the content of loading.html.

**loading.html**

```
<!-- Your loading.html content --->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.post( "request.php", function( data ) {
  $( "body" ).html( data );
});
</script>
```

**request.php**

```
include ("file\where\the\variable\comes\from.php");
$s = shell_exec("powershell path\\to\\script.ps1 '$variable'< NUL");

if (strpos($s, 'True') === false) {
  echo file_get_contents('succes.html'); 
}
else {
  echo file_get_contents('failed.html'); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfect. the only problem was that my servers can't acces internet yet, so i just put the jquery script local.